# Modifying fullcalendar api by diving the day view into 6 parts

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using this `fullcalendar.min.js` and I want to modify the `day` part wherein I want to divide it into 6 parts (similar to the `week` view). And I want to have titles into these 6 parts (Rooms 1-6). Basically, what I am trying to do is to separate the contents in the calendar into 6 parts depending on the room number that they have. So basically the result that I want to get is when I click the `day`, it is divided into 6 parts (instead of 1). And it has titles `room 1, room 2, ... room6`, and the contents under these rooms is depending of the value of the `title: "<%=c.getTitle()%>"` if it contains a string of `Room 1`. I am new to `fullcalendar` so I'm wondering if this is possible.

```
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            editable: false,
            droppable: true,
            drop: function(date, allDay) {
                var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
                var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
                copiedEventObject.start = date;
                copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);
                if($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            },
            events: [
                <%
                    for(CalendarDTO c: list) {
                %>
                {
                    title: "<%=c.getTitle()%>",
                    start: "<%=c.getStart()%>",
                    color: "<%=c.getColor()%>"
                },
                <%}%>
            ]
        });
```

Comment: You probably have to create your own view: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/

Comment: @Slyvain Why can't I customize an existing view? I am precisely following what was indicated in the site